# Limit certain users from filling webform based on their location

Tags: 7, webforms, i18n-l10n

I have a contact us form, that I want only users from the US to see, fill and submit.
And the other users to see that form but a message says "web form is not available in your country" if the user is from outside the sates.
Is there a module to do so? or I just have to make my own? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a module like Smart IP http://drupal.org/project/smart_ip, GeoIP http://drupal.org/project/geoip or just the Maxmind Geolite http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry table to look use the IP address of the user to determine the country.

Then use hook_nodeapi() or hook_node_view(), depending on if you are using Drupal 6 or 7, to redirect the person based on the country.

The pseudo code would look something like this (Drupal 6, using Geoip):

```
function MYMODULE_custom_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
      if ($node->nid == 'NODEID OF WEBFORM') {
        $country = geoip_country_code();
        if (isset($country) && $country != 'us') {
          drupal_goto('node/' . NODEID OF REDIRECT PAGE'); 
        }
      }
     break;
  }
}
```

edit: When I saw 'webform' I assumed you meant using the webform module, hence the nodeapi, but if you are using the basic site contact form you can use hook_menu and create a new callback for the path of the form you are using and create the same kind of check as above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill try this method tonight and will come back to you. thank you so much sir.